# How can I ping my dhcp server using hostname?

Tags: dhcp, hostname, isc-dhcpd

I've just configured a PC with a dhcp server and an apache server on it. I want to set a hostname to my server (i.g "myserver") in order to be able to access its web server by writing on the browser "myserver:80". 
Here's the dhcpd.conf file:

```
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.0.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.0.2.2 192.0.2.254;

  host myserver{
    hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    fixed-address 192.0.2.1;} 
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

edit your /etc/hosts file of your PC and add the following:

```
192.0.2.1    myserver
```

If you'd like to be able to access myserver across the entire network, you'd need to configure an internal DNS server.